# What's a more memory-efficient way of taking part of a byte[]?

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

I've got a `ByteArrayOutputStream` of stereo audio data. Currently I'm doing this, which I know is bad:

```
WaveFileWriter wfw = new WaveFileWriter();
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 1, 2, 44100, false);
byte[] audioData = dataout.toByteArray(); //bad bad bad
int length = audioData.length;
byte[] monoData = new byte[length/2]; //bad bad bad
for(int i = 0; i < length; i+=4){
    monoData[i/2] = audioData[i];
    monoData[1+i/2] = audioData[i+1];
}
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(monoData);
AudioInputStream outStream = new AudioInputStream(bais,format,length);

wfw.write(outStream, Type.WAVE,output);
```

What's a better way of doing this? Can I convert the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a `ByteArrayInputStream` so that I can read from it?

**Edit**

Ok so I've dug into the class that's giving me the `ByteArrayOutputStream` I'm working with. It's being populated with a call to:

```
dataout.write(convbuffer, 0, 2 * vi.channels * bout);
```

I can swap this out for something else if it'll help, but what should I use?

I tried replacing it with:

```
for(int j = 0;j < bout; j += 2){
  dataout.write(convbuffer,2*j,2);
}
```

but that didn't work, not sure why.

Comment: What is `dataout`, where does it come from, and what the heck are you doing?

Comment: It's a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, as I said. I'm skipping every other 2 bytes in order to convert stereo PCM data to mono.

Comment: Are you forced to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` by 3rd party code?

Comment: @MusiGenesis I know what he's trying to do. I want to know why he's chosen a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to hold this data.

Comment: @Adrian yes - it's decoding a Vorbis file.

Comment: @fredley You may not be able to improve much then. If the `ByteArrayOutputStream` was your own decision I'd have suggested wrapping a stream around a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` for access without copying.

Comment: @Adrian Cox, there is a neat way to hack out the underlying `buf` of the ByteArrayOutputStream. I will edit my answer to incl the hack :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you read audio data by one sample at a time, and write the samples to the file as you read them?

<s>Also it seems that your current code overwrites `monoData` pointlessly.</s> — Thanks for the correction, @fredley.

State what you're doing in plain English first; this will help you understand it, and *then* turn to code.

Comment: Ok, I went all out and wrote out the Wave file 'by hand' using a `RandomAccessFile` object, and replacing the call to `dataout.write()` with a little loop, writing out the bytes to disk, 2 at a time. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use instead of the vanilla ByteArrayOutputStream. You get a handy `toByteArrayInputStream()` + `toByteBuffer()` (I tend to use quite a lot of ByteBuffers)

Hopefully many can find the code below useful, some methods are removed form the original class.

Cheers!

```
public class ByteBufStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public ByteBufStream(int initSize){
    super(initSize);
  }
//+few more c-tors, skipped here

  public ByteArrayInputStream toByteArrayInputStream(){
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(getBuf(),0, count);
  }

  public ByteBuffer toByteBuffer(){
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(getBuf(), 0 , count);
  }

  public int capacity(){
    return buf.length;
  }


  public byte[] getBuf(){
    return buf;
  } 



    public final int size() {
        return count;
    }
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)  throws java.io.IOException{
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeInt(capacity());
        out.writeInt(size());

        writeTo(out);
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        in.defaultReadObject();
        int capacity = in.readInt();
        int size = in.readInt();
        byte[] b = new byte[capacity];
        for (int n=0;n<size;){
            int read = in.read(b, n, size-n);
            if (read<0) throw new StreamCorruptedException("can't read buf w/ size:"+size);
            n+=read;
        }
        this.buf = b;
        this.count = size;
    }

}
```

---

*While I generally refrain from teaching hacks, this one is probably harmless, have fun!*

If you want to steal the buf[] off a vanilla ByteArrayOutputStream, look at the following method...

```
public synchronized void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
```

I guess you know what you need to do now:

```
class ByteArrayOutputStreamHack extends OutputStream{
  public ByteArrayInputStream in;
  public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) {
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b, off, len);
  }
  public void write(int b){
   throw new AssertionError();
  }
}
ByteArrayOutputStreamHack hack = new ByteArrayOutputStreamHack()
byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(hack);
ByteArrayInputStream in = hack.in; //we done, we cool :)
```

Comment: @fredley, my bad:   `public byte[] getBuf(){ return buf; } ` for some reason the copy-paste (since I did it in chunks) has left it out. And if you wonder why it's `getBuf()` instead of just `buf` b/c the code was initially outside the class but then moved into it and left there to remember why :)

Comment: That's quite neat.  I was thinking of this approach, which wraps the `java.nio.ByteBuffer`: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CreatinganinputoroutputstreamonaByteBuffer.htm

Comment: @Adrian, the main issue is w/ the wrapping is the you (may) need a growing ByteBuffer (or put can result in BufferOverflowExeption), it requires, a lot more care than the simplistic example to make some use of. On bufferoverflow the standard approach is new buf/flip/put, reassign but it totally takes the benefit of the fixed capacity ByteBuffer. A lot better would be to flush the buffer to whatever next level socket/file/etc is, instead buffering the entire content. (I guess I'm  going too off the topic, so I stop here)

Answer (score -1):

Like `new ByteArrayInputStream(dataout.toByteArray())`?

Comment: this is exactly not memory efficient since toByteArray does copy the underlying byte[]. for large byte[] it is quite inefficient.